# Trouble getting few items from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse some items from a webpage. I can't get it working in anyway. The items I'm after are (perhaps) within `iframe`. I tried to switch it but that doesn't have any effect. I'm still getting nothing except for `TimeoutException` when it hits the line where I tried to switch the `iframe`. How can i get it working. Thanks in advance:

Here goes the webpage link: [URL](http://tvc4.forexpros.com/init.php?family_prefix=tvc4&carrier=64694b96ed4909e815f1d10605ae4e83&time=1513525898&domain_ID=70&lang_ID=70&timezone_ID=31&pair_ID=171&interval=86400&refresh=4&session=session&client=1&user=200743128&width=650&height=750&init_page=instrument&m_pids=&watchlist=&site=https://au.investing.com&version=1.11.2)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "replace_with_above_url"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "tradingview_fe623")))

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".quick .apply-common-tooltip"))):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

Elements within which the items I'm after:

```
<div class="quick">
    <span class="apply-common-tooltip">5</span>
    <span class="apply-common-tooltip">1h</span>
    <span class="apply-common-tooltip selected">1D</span>
    <span class="apply-common-tooltip">1M</span>
    <span class="apply-common-tooltip">1D</span>
</div>
```

This is the output I'm expecting to have (it works locally when i try to get them using css selectors):

```
5
1h
1D
1M
1D
```

This is how it looks in the web:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required nodes located inside 2 nested iframes, so you need to switch to them one by one. Note that `id`/`name` of second one generated dynamically. Just try to replace

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "tradingview_fe623")))
```

with

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".abs")))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id^='tradingview_']")))
```

Comment: You are just impossible sir Andersson. Yep, you made it.